# Apache: add POST parameter to every request

Tags: apache-2.2, php, xdebug

Is there a way to add fixed POST parameter to every request apache passes to the php?

I can change pretty much anything on the server: .htaccess, httpd.conf, php.ini. Both parameter's name and value are fixed strings. To be specific, I'm trying to enable remote Xdebug that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating this script somewhere in your include path

```
<?php
    $_POST['xdebug'] = 'true'; #or whatever you need
```

and setting it as the [auto-prepend-file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).